# High concurvity/ collinearity between time and temperature in GAM predicting deaths but low ACF. Does this matter?

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, multicollinearity, generalized-additive-model, concurvity

I have problems with concurvity in my thesis research, and don't have access to a statistician who works with time series, GAMs or R. I'd be very grateful for any (partial) answer, however short. I'll gladly return the favour where I can! For really helpful input I'd be more than happy to offer co-authorship on publication. Deadlines are very close, and I'm heading towards having no results at all if I can't solve this concurvity issue :(

I'm using GAMs to try to understand the relationship between deaths and heat-related variables (e.g. temperature and humidity), using daily time series over a 14-year period from a tropical, low-income country. My aim is to understand the relationship between these variables and deaths, rather than pure prediction performance.

The GAMs include distributed lag models (set up as 7-column matrices, see code at bottom of post), since deaths may occur over several days following exposure.

Simple GAMs with just time, lagged temperature and lagged precipitation (a potential confounder) show very high concurvity between lagged temperature and time, regardless of the many different ways I have tried to decompose time, such as  `te(year, doy)` with a cyclic spline for doy and various choices for k or as `s(time)` with various k, or as `te(year, month) + s(doy)`, or as `te(year, month) + s(monthday)` to name a few, but concurvity with temperature never drops below 0.8 for at least one of the time terms.

The autocorrelation functions (ACF) however, shows values close to zero, only just about breaching the 'significance line' in a few instances. It does show patterning though, although the regularity is difficult to define.

**1) Should I be worried about the high concurvity, or can I ignore it given the mostly non-significant ACF?** I've read dozens of heat-mortality modelling studies and none report on concurvity between weather variables and time (though one 2012 paper discussed autocorrelation).

**2) If I cannot ignore it, what should I do to resolve it?** I've seen [a 2012 paper by Yang et al.](https://doi.org/10.1186/1471-2288-12-165) that proposes including an autoregressive term based on a moving average. My mathematical knowledge is insufficient to follow their statistical argument. But in a distributed lag model wouldn't this adjust away part of the effect of the exposure (see directed acyclic graph below, in which D is death and E is exposure)? (For those interested in DAGs, distributed lag and autoregressive terms, see [paper by Barnett et al (2017)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S001393511630929X)

I've also come across [sequential regression](https://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar?output=instlink&q=info:PKdjq7ZwozEJ:scholar.google.com/&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5&scillfp=17865929886710916120&oi=lle). Would this be more or less appropriate? If appropriate, a pointer to an example would be really appreciated!

[image: DAG of exposure, death and distributed lag]

Some examples of simplified GAMs and their model output are shown below. (They do not yet include further complicating terms such as specific humidity yet, which is not only highly concurved with time as well, but also shows high concurvity with temperature - which will be the next problem to figure out):

```r
conc38b <- gam(deaths~te(year, month, week, weekday, bs=c("cr","cc","cc","cc")) + heap +
                      te(temp_max, lag, k=c(10, 3)) + 
                      te(precip_daily_total, lag, k=c(10, 3)), 
                      data = dat, family = nb, method = 'REML', select = TRUE, 
                      knots = list(month = c(0.5, 12.5), week = c(0.5, 52.5), weekday = c(0, 6.5)))
```

Concurvity for the above model between (temp_max, lag) and (year, month, week, weekday) is 0.91:

```r
$worst
                                    para te(year,month,week,weekday) te(temp_max,lag) te(precip_daily_total,lag)
para                        1.000000e+00                1.125625e-29        0.3150073                  0.6666348
te(year,month,week,weekday) 1.400648e-29                1.000000e+00        0.9060552                  0.6652313
te(temp_max,lag)            3.152795e-01                8.998113e-01        1.0000000                  0.5781015
te(precip_daily_total,lag)  6.666348e-01                6.652313e-01        0.5805159                  1.0000000
```

Output from `gam.check()`:

```r
Method: REML   Optimizer: outer newton
full convergence after 16 iterations.
Gradient range [-0.01467332,0.003096643]
(score 8915.994 & scale 1).
Hessian positive definite, eigenvalue range [5.048053e-05,26.50175].
Model rank =  544 / 544 

Basis dimension (k) checking results. Low p-value (k-index<1) may
indicate that k is too low, especially if edf is close to k'.

                                  k'      edf k-index p-value  
te(year,month,week,weekday) 319.0000  26.6531    0.96    0.06 .
te(temp_max,lag)             29.0000   3.3681      NA      NA  
te(precip_daily_total,lag)   27.0000   0.0051      NA      NA  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Some output from `summary(conc38b)`:

```r
Family: Negative Binomial(16.731) 
Link function: log 

Formula:
deaths ~ te(year, month, week, weekday, bs = c("cr", "cc", "cc", 
    "cc")) + heap + te(temp_max, lag, k = c(10, 3)) + te(precip_daily_total, 
    lag, k = c(10, 3))

Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  0.64899    0.01232  52.682  < 2e-16 ***
heap1        2.86624    0.29947   9.571  < 2e-16 ***
heap2        3.10842    0.29631  10.491  < 2e-16 ***
heap3        2.97093    0.30629   9.700  < 2e-16 ***
.
.
.
heap166      2.10391    0.36571   5.753 8.77e-09 ***
heap167      2.36096    0.34824   6.780 1.20e-11 ***
heap168      2.14366    0.36435   5.884 4.01e-09 ***

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
                                  edf Ref.df  Chi.sq p-value    
te(year,month,week,weekday) 26.653127    319 166.803 < 2e-16 ***
te(temp_max,lag)             3.368129     27  11.130 0.00145 ** 
te(precip_daily_total,lag)   0.005104     27   0.002 0.69636    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.839   Deviance explained = 53.3%
-REML =   8916  Scale est. = 1         n = 5107
```

Below are the ACF plots (note limit y-axis = 0.1 for clarity of pattern). They show peaks at 5 and 15, and then there seems to be a recurring pattern at multiples of approx. 30 (suggesting month is not modelled adequately?). Not sure what would cause the spikes at 5 and 15. There is heaping of deaths on the 15th day of each month, to which deaths with unknown date were allocated. This heaping was modelled with categorical variable/ factor `heap` with 169 levels (0 for all non-heaping days and 1-168 (i.e. 14 * 12 for each subsequent heaping day over the 14-year period):

[image]
[image]

I get an almost identical looking ACF when I decompose time into (year, month, monthday) as in model conc39 below, although concurvity between (temp_max, lag) and the time term has now dropped somewhat to 0.83:

```r
conc39 <- gam(deaths~te(year, month, monthday, bs=c("cr","cc","cr")) + heap + 
                     te(temp_max, lag, k=c(10, 4)) + 
                     te(precip_daily_total, lag, k=c(10, 4)), 
                     data = dat, family = nb, method = 'REML', select = TRUE, 
                     knots = list(month = c(0.5, 12.5)))
```

```r
Method: REML   Optimizer: outer newton
full convergence after 14 iterations.
Gradient range [-0.001578187,6.155096e-05]
(score 8915.763 & scale 1).
Hessian positive definite, eigenvalue range [1.894391e-05,26.99215].
Model rank =  323 / 323 

Basis dimension (k) checking results. Low p-value (k-index<1) may
indicate that k is too low, especially if edf is close to k'.

                                k'     edf k-index p-value    
te(year,month,monthday)    79.0000 25.0437    0.93  <2e-16 ***
te(temp_max,lag)           39.0000  4.0875      NA      NA    
te(precip_daily_total,lag) 36.0000  0.0107      NA      NA    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Some output from `summary(conc39)`:

```r
Family: Negative Binomial(17.425) 
Link function: log 

Formula:
deaths ~ te(year, month, monthday, bs = c("cr", "cc", "cr")) + 
    heap + te(temp_max, lag, k = c(10, 4)) + te(precip_daily_total, 
    lag, k = c(10, 4))

Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  0.65212    0.01192  54.730  < 2e-16 ***
heap1        2.95631    0.29804   9.919  < 2e-16 ***
heap2        3.12892    0.29430  10.632  < 2e-16 ***
heap3        2.98661    0.30594   9.762  < 2e-16 ***
.
.
.
heap166      2.01439    0.36452   5.526 3.27e-08 ***
heap167      2.27565    0.34640   6.569 5.05e-11 ***
heap168      2.05709    0.36330   5.662 1.49e-08 ***

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
                                edf Ref.df  Chi.sq  p-value    
te(year,month,monthday)    38.75573     99 187.231  < 2e-16 ***
te(temp_max,lag)            4.06437     37  25.927 1.66e-06 ***
te(precip_daily_total,lag)  0.01173     36   0.008    0.557    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.839   Deviance explained = 53.8%
-REML =   8915  Scale est. = 1         n = 5107
```

```r
$worst
                                   para te(year,month,monthday) te(temp_max,lag) te(precip_daily_total,lag)
para                       1.000000e+00            3.261007e-31        0.3313549                  0.6666532
te(year,month,monthday)    3.060763e-31            1.000000e+00        0.8266086                  0.5670777
te(temp_max,lag)           3.331014e-01            8.225942e-01        1.0000000                  0.5840875
te(precip_daily_total,lag) 6.666532e-01            5.670777e-01        0.5939380                  1.0000000
```

The default approach in time series studies of heat-mortality is to model time with fixed df, generally between 7-10 df per year of data. I am, however, apprehensive about this approach because a) mortality profiles vary with locality due to sociodemographic and environmental characteristics and b) the choice of df is based on higher income countries (where nearly all these studies have been done) with different mortality profiles and so may not be appropriate for tropical, low-income countries.

Although the approach of fixing (high) df does remove more temporal patterns from the ACF (see model and output below), concurvity between time and lagged temperature has now risen to 0.99! Moreover, temperature (which has been a consistent, highly significant predictor in every model of the tens (hundreds?) I have run, has now turned non-significant. I am guessing this is because time is now a very wiggly function that not only models/ removes seasonal variation, but also some of the day-to-day variation that is needed for the temperature smooth  :

```r
conc20a <- gam(deaths~s(time, k=112, fx=TRUE) + heap + 
                      te(temp_max, lag, k=c(10,3)) + 
                      te(precip_daily_total, lag, k=c(10,3)), 
                      data = dat, family = nb, method = 'REML', select = TRUE)
```

Output from `gam.check(conc20a, rep = 1000)`:

```r
Method: REML   Optimizer: outer newton
full convergence after 9 iterations.
Gradient range [-0.0008983099,9.546022e-05]
(score 8750.13 & scale 1).
Hessian positive definite, eigenvalue range [0.0001420112,15.40832].
Model rank =  336 / 336 

Basis dimension (k) checking results. Low p-value (k-index<1) may
indicate that k is too low, especially if edf is close to k'.

                                 k'      edf k-index p-value
s(time)                    111.0000 111.0000    0.98    0.56
te(temp_max,lag)            29.0000   0.6548      NA      NA
te(precip_daily_total,lag)  27.0000   0.0046      NA      NA
```

Output from `concurvity(conc20a, full=FALSE)$worst`:

```r
                                   para      s(time) te(temp_max,lag) te(precip_daily_total,lag)
para                       1.000000e+00 2.462064e-19        0.3165236                  0.6666348
s(time)                    2.462398e-19 1.000000e+00        0.9930674                  0.6879284
te(temp_max,lag)           3.170844e-01 9.356384e-01        1.0000000                  0.5788711
te(precip_daily_total,lag) 6.666348e-01 6.879284e-01        0.5788381                  1.0000000
```

Some output from `summary(conc20a)`:

```r
Family: Negative Binomial(22.701) 
Link function: log 

Formula:
deaths ~ s(time, k = 112, fx = TRUE) + heap + te(temp_max, lag, 
    k = c(10, 3)) + te(precip_daily_total, lag, k = c(10, 3))

Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  0.62502    0.01116  56.020  < 2e-16 ***
heap1        2.78784    0.29888   9.328  < 2e-16 ***
heap2        3.42923    0.28859  11.883  < 2e-16 ***
heap3        2.98953    0.28943  10.329  < 2e-16 ***
.
.
.
heap166      2.18330    0.35564   6.139 8.30e-10 ***
heap167      2.50739    0.34453   7.278 3.40e-13 ***
heap168      2.25574    0.35824   6.297 3.04e-10 ***

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
                                 edf Ref.df  Chi.sq p-value    
s(time)                    1.110e+02    111 419.375  <2e-16 ***
te(temp_max,lag)           6.548e-01     27   0.895   0.249    
te(precip_daily_total,lag) 4.598e-03     27   0.002   0.868    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.843   Deviance explained = 56.1%
-REML = 8750.1  Scale est. = 1         n = 5107
```

ACF functions:

[image]
[image]

The data look as follows:

```r
    deaths_total       date time year month week doy monthday weekday heap heap_bin temp_max precip_daily_total
466            5 2002-04-11  466 2002     4   14 101       11       4    0        0    40.15               1.35
467            0 2002-04-12  467 2002     4   14 102       12       5    0        0    38.45               5.40
468            5 2002-04-13  468 2002     4   14 103       13       6    0        0    34.65               5.13
469            2 2002-04-14  469 2002     4   15 104       14       0    0        0    37.39               0.09
470           35 2002-04-15  470 2002     4   15 105       15       1   16        1    34.50               6.80
471            4 2002-04-16  471 2002     4   15 106       16       2    0        0    36.49               0.12
```

where time is a counter of days over the 14-year period (running from 1-5113) and doy = day of year (running from 1-366)

Data can be found on my [GitHub](https://github.com/JadeShodan/heat-mortality) site in the file [data_cross_validated_post2.rds](https://github.com/JadeShodan/heat-mortality/blob/main/data_cross_validated_post2.rds). A csv version is also available. This is my code:

```r
library(readr)
library(mgcv)

df <- read_rds("data_crossvalidated_post2.rds")

# Create matrices for lagged weather variables (6 day lags) based on example by Simon Wood 
# in his 2017 book ("Generalized additive models: an introduction with R", p. 349) and 
# gamair package documentation (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gamair/gamair.pdf, p. 54)

lagard <- function(x,n.lag=7) {
n <- length(x); X <- matrix(NA,n,n.lag)
for (i in 1:n.lag) X[i:n,i] <- x[i:n-i+1]
X
}

dat <- list(lag=matrix(0:6,nrow(df),7,byrow=TRUE), deaths=df$deaths_total,doy=df$doy, year = df$year, month = df$month, weekday = df$weekday, week = df$week, monthday = df$monthday, time = df$time, heap=df$heap, heap_bin = df$heap_bin, precip_hourly_dailysum = df$precip_hourly_dailysum)
dat$temp_max <- lagard(df$temp_max)
dat$temp_min <- lagard(df$temp_min)
dat$temp_mean <- lagard(df$temp_mean)
dat$wbgt_max <- lagard(df$wbgt_max)
dat$wbgt_mean <- lagard(df$wbgt_mean)
dat$wbgt_min <- lagard(df$wbgt_min)
dat$temp_wb_nasa_max <- lagard(df$temp_wb_nasa_max)
dat$sh_mean <- lagard(df$sh_mean)
dat$solar_mean <- lagard(df$solar_mean)
dat$wind2m_mean <- lagard(df$wind2m_mean)
dat$sh_max <- lagard(df$sh_max)
dat$solar_max <- lagard(df$solar_max)
dat$wind2m_max <- lagard(df$wind2m_max)
dat$temp_wb_nasa_mean <- lagard(df$temp_wb_nasa_mean)
dat$precip_hourly_dailysum <- lagard(df$precip_hourly_dailysum)
dat$precip_hourly <- lagard(df$precip_hourly)
dat$precip_daily_total <- lagard( df$precip_daily_total)
dat$temp <- lagard(df$temp)
dat$sh <- lagard(df$sh)
dat$rh <- lagard(df$rh)
dat$solar <- lagard(df$solar)
dat$wind2m <- lagard(df$wind2m)


conc38b <- gam(deaths~te(year, month, week, weekday, bs=c("cr","cc","cc","cc")) + heap +
                      te(temp_max, lag, k=c(10, 3)) + 
                      te(precip_daily_total, lag, k=c(10, 3)), 
                      data = dat, family = nb, method = 'REML', select = TRUE, 
                      knots = list(month = c(0.5, 12.5), week = c(0.5, 52.5), weekday = c(0, 6.5)))

conc39 <- gam(deaths~te(year, month, monthday, bs=c("cr","cc","cr")) + heap + 
                     te(temp_max, lag, k=c(10, 4)) + 
                     te(precip_daily_total, lag, k=c(10, 4)), 
                     data = dat, family = nb, method = 'REML', select = TRUE, 
                     knots = list(month = c(0.5, 12.5)))

conc20a <- gam(deaths~s(time, k=112, fx=TRUE) + heap + 
                      te(temp_max, lag, k=c(10,3)) + 
                      te(precip_daily_total, lag, k=c(10,3)), 
                      data = dat, family = nb, method = 'REML', select = TRUE)
```

Thank you if you've read this far!! :-))

Comment: Naturally, I have tried to see how other studies on this topic have approached this problem, but can't find any useful papers for the following main reasons:
a) most studies use GLM with a distributed lag non-linear model (dlnm) and fix the df
b) these studies don't tend to report on collinearity/ concurvity (for reasons I'm not sure of)
c) since the arrival of the dlnm framework in 2011, almost nobody uses GAMs anymore in heat-mortality, so only older GAM studies tend to be available for which no model code is published to see how exactly people have specified their models

Comment: The default approach of GLM + [dlnm](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/sim.3940) makes use of R's splines package. I'm not familiar with this package and don't know if concurvity can be calculated with it. If not, I'm wondering if this is the reason why concurvity is not reported in other studies (even though this is likely to be an issue in all time series studies of heat-mortality).